# How do i add json data to mysql database in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, database

I am to get the json data from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

I want to populate the mysql database with the id,name,username and email from  the json data.
I am using a node module called 'request' to read the online json api

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: 'nodemysql'
});
connect
db.connect((err) => {
   if (err) {
       throw err
   }
   console.log('MySql Connected...');

});
app.get('/populate', (req, res) => {
   request({
       url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
       json: true
   }, (err, res, body) => {
       res.send(body);
   });
})
```

Here's a two samples of the items in the json api

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }
```

I just need the id,name,username and email  to be added the mysql database as columns for each user as rows

Comment: What is your MySQL version? *Here's a two samples of the items in the json api* Does you want to add 2 records with one query? or each record with separate query?

Comment: There are 10 records actually, i want to add them all in one query.

Comment: It is easy if you have 8.0.4 version or above. If your version is ancient then I'd recommend to perform insertion via stored procedure.

Comment: yes it is version 10.4.11

Comment: MySQL have no such version. Maybe your server id MariaDB 10.4.11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

> yes it is version 10.4.11 – Preshy Jones

means you have MariaDB:

```sql
SELECT idx + 1, 
       JSON_VALUE(single_object, '$.id') id,
       JSON_VALUE(single_object, '$.name') name,
       JSON_VALUE(single_object, '$.username') username,
       JSON_VALUE(single_object, '$.email') email
FROM ( SELECT idx, JSON_EXTRACT(@json, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')) single_object
       FROM ( SELECT 0 idx UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) idxs ) objects
HAVING id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=bfbd7f4326a1543b25fac3f9a17cd36f)

Pay attention - separate JSON objects are transferred into the query as JSON array, not as JSON object.

The number of consecutive numbers in the 'idxs' subquery must start from zero and contain at least as many numbers as the number of individual objects in the source data. If not, the remaining rows will be lost. This subquery may be easily replaced with numberlist-generated recursive CTE.